# NextJs: cannot execute function imported from .ts file inside TSX, throws ModuleNotFound error

Tags: typescript, next.js, tsx, react-tsx

I have an issue which is likely related to using NextJs with typescript.

Example:

```
// /pages/index.tsx

import _ from 'lodash' 

export const MyComponent = () => {
  return {
   <ul>{
    _.map(someArray, el => <li>{el}</li>) // Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
   }</ul>
}
```

I have the same error also for my own functions, not only with lodash functions.

If I import a function from a .ts file into my .tsx file and then execute it inside TSX, I get a ModuleNotFound error, also sometimes `ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'`. I can however import and execute a custom function imported from a .js file.

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^1.6.22",
    "@next/mdx": "^11.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "next-mdx-remote": "^3.0.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-markdown": "^6.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.172",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.30.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^11.1.2"
  }
}
```

next.config:

```
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx$/
})

module.exports = withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx', 'md', 'mdx'],
})
```

I guess I missed something when configuration NextJs to work with TSX and Typescript.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### **Rather look like a syntax error**

Your component should be returned with a `()` to return direct JSX.

And also, named import lodash function like so: `import { map } from "lodash";` this will help on [code-splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/)

**So, you component should be like so:**

```
import _ from "lodash";

export const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {_.map(someArray, el => (
        <li>{el}</li>
      ))
      }
    </ul>
  );
};
```

**OR [implicitly returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=vi#function_body):**

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export const MyComponent = () => (
  <ul>
    {_.map(someArray, el => (
      <li>{el}</li>
    ))
      }
  </ul>
);
```

**OR you probably don't need to use lodash map in your case:**

Just use js [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
export const MyComponent = () => (
  <ul>
    {someArray.map(el => (
      <li key={el}>{el}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. However changing it to `return (..)` does not fix the issue.

Comment: Try to import lodash like: `import { map } from "lodash";` see if it works?

Comment: And you might not need to use lodash for your case, like the last section in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code splitting improvement.

Comment: using `import { map } from "lodash"`or VanillaJS `map` both don't work. No function, also not functions I define myself, are working in this context when used inside TSX so I guess the error lies in my NextJS/typescript configuration. Please note that executing functions in NextJS `getStaticProps` works.

Comment: I see, so the error might causing by somewhere else in the configuration.

Comment: Solved. The issue was when configuring the mdx module, see solution here: https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/plkc51/cannot_import_function_from_another_file_in_my/

Comment: Can you please post answer how actually you solved this issue? @LaurentDellere

Comment: @SuroorAhmmad My issue had nothing to do wit typescript or TSX. The problem was coming from the @next/mdx package. The serializer function from that package can only be used inside a /pages template in NextJs.

Answer (score 0):

The error had nothing to do with typescript. The issue was that I used `serialize` from next-mdx-remote package outside NextJS `pages` directory which does not work.